# Contiguity for simplicial maps between simplicial sets

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complexes

I begin by recalling the definition of contiguous simplicial maps between abstract simplicial complexes:

**Definition.** Two simplicial maps $\varphi,\psi\colon K \to L$ are said to be *contiguous* if for every simplex $\sigma \in K$, $\varphi(\sigma) \cup \psi(\sigma)$ is a simplex of $L$.

Now I wonder whether this notion has been extended for more general contexts such as simplicial sets or $\Delta$-complexes.

**Question.** Has it been studied a notion of contiguity for simplicial maps between simplicial sets (or $\Delta$-complexes)? If that is the case could you provide me a reference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a partial answer to your question is provided in the paper(wanted to post as a comment but don't have enough reputation)

*Grayson, Daniel R.*, Finite generation of K-groups of a curve over a finite field. (After Daniel Quillen), Algebraic (K)-theory, Proc. Conf., Oberwolfach 1980, Part I, Lect. Notes Math. 966, 69-90 (1982). [ZBL0502.14004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0502.14004).

The exact references are Definition 1.2 and Definition 1.7.
One should beware of a typo in the definition 1.2, where **f,g are said to be adjacent if the set $\{f(x)|x \in \sigma, x \leq x'\} \cup \{g(x)|x \in \sigma, x \leq x'\}$**. The **correct** definition should be

**Definition:** Two simplicial maps $f,g:X \rightarrow Y$ between ordered simplicial complexes $X,Y$ are said to be adjacent if for any simplex $\sigma$ and any $x' \in \sigma$, the set $$\{f(x)|x \in \sigma, x \leq x'\} \cup \{g(x)|x \in \sigma, x' \leq x\}$$ is a simplex in Y.

Then Corollary 1.3 says that adjacent simplicial maps are homotopic(meaning the induced maps between geometric realizations are homotopic).